# Rails unknown attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I got an error in My rails application

[image]

Code looks like this:

oders_controller.rb

```
 def payMovie
    @order = OrderMovie.new
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    @order.user = @user
    @movie = Movie.find params[:id]

    puts "sssssssssssss"
    puts @movie.inspect

    @order.price = @movie.movieprice
    @order.currency = @movie.currency
    @order.movie << @movie
    if @order.save
      flash[:notice] = t("flash.saved")
      redirect_to :back
    else
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end
```

models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comment
  has_and_belongs_to_many :knowledgeprovider
  has_and_belongs_to_many :channel
  belongs_to :oder_movie
```

models/order_movie.rb

```
class OrderMovie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user
  has_one :movie
end
```

What could be the problem?

Thanks for your help

UPDATE

```
@order.inspect
<OrderMovie id: nil, price: nil, currency: nil, user_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, movie_id: nil>

@user.inspect
<User id: 3, firstname: "Felix", lastname: "Hohlweglersad"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your User model relations are not good, if you're trying to make has_many :through relation between users and movies with order_movies, your user must has_many :order_movies not belongs_to :order_movies.
So this error tells you that you don't have order_movie_id foreign key in your users table because you defined wrong relation. So change:

```
belongs_to :order_movie
```

to

```
has_many :order_movies
```

In your User model.

Comment: I would suggest you that you change relations in OrderMovie to belongs_to from has_one...

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution.You have spelled wrong in belongs_to :order_movie statement

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comment
  has_and_belongs_to_many :knowledgeprovider
  has_and_belongs_to_many :channel
  belongs_to :order_movie
```

If you don't have order_movie foreign key then run this migratuons

```
add_column :users,:order_movie_id,:integer
    add_foreign_key :users,:order_movies
```

Comment: yes exactly thats one problem. Fixed that thanks. but still the same error pending

Comment: please give the result by puts of the above two statments user = User.find(session[:user_id])
   order.user = @user

Comment: Do you have the foreign key in the users table?

Comment: added the two wars above and the printscreen of the table. I have the foreign keys. have set references while migration  `t.references :user` and `t.references :movie`

Comment: but you don't have the foreign key of order_movie_id in users table

Comment: why aren't they added? when i do the references stuff? do I have to add them manually now?